# How to create zebra-stripe CSS with TAL?

Tags: css, zope, template-tal, chameleon, zpt

How can I use Chameleon or Zope Page Templates to easily create CSS zebra striping? I want to add `odd` and `even` classes to each row in a table, but using a condition with `repeat/name/odd` or `repeat/name/even` looks rather verbose even with a conditional expression:

```html
<table>
   <tr tal:repeat="row rows" 
       tal:attributes="class python:repeat['row'].odd and 'odd' or 'even'">
       <td tal:repeat="col row" tal:content="col">column text text</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This gets especially tedious if you have multiple classes to calculate.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Zope Page Templates implementation for the `repeat` variable has an under-documented *extra* parameter, `parity`, than gives you the string `'odd'` or `'even'`, alternating between iterations:

```html
<table>
   <tr tal:repeat="row rows" 
       tal:attributes="class repeat/row/parity">
       <td tal:repeat="col row" tal:content="col">column text text</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is also much easier to interpolate into a string expression:

```html
tal:attributes="class string:striped ${row/class} ${repeat/row/parity}"
```

This works in Chameleon as well.